# Python Phonebook program

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this program, and it is almost perfect but I need the dictionary to print on separate lines like so:

```
Please enter a name (or just press enter to end the input): Tom
Please enter Tom's phone: 555-5555

Please enter a name (or just press enter to end the input): Sue
Please enter Sue's phone: 333-3333

Please enter a name (or just press enter to end the input): Ann
Please enter Ann's phone: 222-2222

Please enter a name (or just press enter to end the input): 
Thank you. 

Your phonebook contains the following entries:

Sue 333-3333

Tom 555-5555

Ann 222-2222
```

Here is my code:

```
def main():

phoneBook = {}
name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
while name != '':
    number = input("Please enter number: ")
    phoneBook[name] = number
    name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
    if name == '':
        print("Thank You!")

print("Your phonebook contains the following entries:\n",phoneBook)


main()
```

Comment: why don't you just use `\n`??

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the entries in your phonebook and print them one at a time:

```
for name, number in phoneBook.items():
    print ("%s %s" % (name, number))
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
strs = "\n".join( " ".join((name,num)) for name,num in phoneBook.items() )
print("Your phonebook contains the following entries:\n",strs)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to write codes yourself, `pprint` could be an option:

```
import pprint

....

print("Your phonebook contains the following entries:\n")
pprint.pprint(phoneBook)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) to make your life easy:

```
for i in phoneBook.iteritems():
    print("{0} {1}".format(*i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_dictionary = {}
while True:
    name = str(input("Enter a name: "))
    if name == "":
        break
    elif name in my_dictionary:
        print "Phone Number: " + my_dictionary[name]
    else:
        phone_number = input("Enter this person's number: ")
        my_dictionary[name] = phone_number
print my_dictionary
```